# JSESSIONID use existing session cookies

Tags: spring-session

Spring Session uses a different format for its session cookies than Tomcat does. So if you implement Spring Session, even if you would name the session cookie JSESSIONID, all the users have to login again.

This is a point where you potentially lose users, because nobody likes to login. Perhaps this is an edge case, and certainly it's not worth a huge amount of trouble, but I'm curious if it's possible for existing users to use their already stored Tomcat session cookies?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own `org.springframework.session.web.http.CookieSerializer` that matches Tomcat's default cookie serialization and register it as a bean.

Spring Session configuration will then pick it up and use it - see `org.springframework.session.config.annotation.web.http.SpringHttpSessionConfiguration#setCookieSerializer` for more details.